# Combine SIMILAR value rows using Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Suppose I have the following Dataframe-

```
company                           money
jack & jill, Boston, MA 02215        51
jack & jill, MA 02215                49
```

Now, I know that these 2 rows mean the same company, so I want to merge them and also sum the money-

```
company                           money
jack & jill, Boston, MA 02215       100
```

I don't care about the format of the company name, as long as the duplicates get merged and the money gets added.

How should I go about this? Is there a library out there that merges SIMILAR value rows and sums the corresponding quantitative value?

Comment: Have a look at fuzzywuzzy: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: try using `company.startswith('jack & jill')` and then groupby using the company column.

Comment: @AnanthReddy This is just an example. There are 1000's of rows with multiple company names.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Thanks for the suggestion! Although, how do you reckon I use it with a CSV file where there can be, for example, 4 rows with similar company names? How do iterate my CSV file?

Edit: I found this http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/fuzzing-matching-in-pandas-with-fuzzywuzzy/ which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same pattern in `company` column i.e. the value before the 1st comma is company name. You can use something like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'company':['jack & jill, Boston, MA 02215','jack & jill, MA 02215','Google, New Jersey', 'Google'], 
                   'money':[51,49, 33, 22]})


df['company'] = df['company'].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])

new_df = df.groupby(['company'])['money'].sum().reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    company money
0   Google  55
1   jack & jill 100
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the same pattern in all the company names. Hence, I wanna look at something that helps me calculate the similarity between 2 strings. I think something like fuzzywuzzy might help me out. But I'm not sure if I can use it on a CSV file with 1000's of rows.

Edit: I found this http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/fuzzing-matching-in-pandas-with-fuzzywuzzy/ which might be useful.